# Understanding Eloquent JS (Excercise 2.3)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on Chapter 2 Exercise 3 in Eloquent Javascript, Chess Board. I am having an issue understanding one part and hoping someone would be able to provide a little enlightenment.

My Code:

```
var size = 7;
var board = "";
for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j <= size; j++){
        if((i + j) % 2 === 0){
            board += " ";
        } else {
            board += "#";
        }
    }
    board += "\n";
}
console.log(board);
```

The issue that I am having is with the condition of the "if" statement.

```
if((i + j) % 2 === 0)
```

I am not understanding why I need to add i and j together. Isn't the first "for" loop that contains the i variable constructing the row and how many rows? Where as, the second "for" loop that contains the j variable is creating the content within each row?

Comment: That condition can be broken down to `even(i) && even(j) || odd(i) && odd(j)`. Can you make the equivalence? (Tip: try to get to `even(i) == even(j)` as a middle step)

Answer (score 1):

It is creating a checker board pattern so the rows are off by one on each iteration. If the row was not used, it would create stripes.

Currently with `i + j % 2`

```
  # # # #
 # # # # #
  # # # #
 # # # # #
```

If it were just `j % 2`

```
  # # # #
  # # # #
  # # # #
  # # # #
```

If it were just `i % 2`

```
.
 ########

 ########

 ########
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize if my wording for the part that I wasn't understanding was not very clear. My disconnect is why do I have to even add `i` and `j`. Why is it that I can't just use `if(j % 2 === 0)`? I see that it doesn't produce the right results, but why?

Comment: The question is 100% clear. If you just use j, than all the columns would be lined up. It is making even and odd when you add the row to it. Run the code just with j or i and see it for yourself. It is not hard to do.

Comment: Thank you. It is starting to make more sense. I figured that was it, but reassurance helps confirm ideas. I was also over complicating it.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of i and j is to create the checkerboard pattern. If the sum is even, a white square (" ") is printed; otherwise it is black ("#").

Also, your conditional statement contains a triple equals sign instead of the desired ==.

Comment: Why would you think that `==` was more desired than `===`?

Comment: Perhaps "desired" was a poor word choice; if functionality isn't affected, then I suppose it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't matter in this case, and while I personally do prefer the shorter `==` then, the common advise is to always use `===`

Comment: Yeah the `===` is just mainly advised from everything I've been reading. For the question I am asking, I understand what the code is saying. Where the disconnect is why would I have to add `i` and `j` in the first place. Why can't I just `if(j % 2 === 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I think I'am a little late to answer but will do so anyway.

Its because your want to create a pattern that looks like something like this.

```
"# # # #"
" # # # "
```

therefor you are going to add the variable "i" that is used to count from your outer loop and the variable "j" from your inner loop that is used to count, to decide with the help of an if/else statement to output either a "#" or " "(space). Also not that your first outer loop will stay at 0 until the vairable "j" in your inner loop is equal to "size". Meaning that one the first run (i+j) is = to 0+1, 0+2, 0+3, 0+4, 0+5, 0+6, 0+7. Once the inner loop is done the outer loop adds a "\n" and  the procces is repeated but this time your outer loop vairable that is used to count changes from 0 to 1 and your inner loop variable that is used to count resets to 0 and your expression (i+j) is now equal to 1+0, 1+2, 1+3 ect

```
var size = 7;
var board = "";
for(var i = 0; i <= size; i++){ /*This will remain 0 the first run until the inner loop is completed then it will add the "\n" at the end*/
for(var j = 0; j <= size; j++){/* the variable j here will keep adding 1 to itslef until it j is equal to size*/
    if((i + j) % 2 === 0){/* here it will add both i+j then divide it by 2 in order to see if is an even number or not. 
                            remember it will look something like the this first run 0+1, 0+2, 0+3 ect.*/
        board += " ";// here if the number is even it will output a (space) 
    } else {
        board += "#";// here if the number is not even it adds "#"
    } // finally this inner loop gets repeated until your vairable "j" is equal to "size" 
}
board += "\n";/* then the outer loop adds a new line and your vairable "i" 
              becomes 1 and this whole loop gets reapeated until "i" is equal to "size"*/
}
console.log(board);
```

hope this helped excuse my grammar, my english is not that good greetings from Mexico City